# React check null for props function call

Tags: reactjs

I am using two methods from props.

//This two method are not required.

```
this.props.onClose({ somthing });
this.props.onSubmit({ somthing });
```

I want to check if `onClose` or `onSubmit` is null then it should not trigger.

I know i can do like:

```
const { onSubmit, onClose } = this.props;
if (onClose) {
    onClose({ submitted: true });
}
if (onSubmit) {
    onSubmit({ submitted: true });
}
```

But, it will increase line of code. Is there any possibility to check `null` easily?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the shorter version:

```
const { onSubmit, onClose } = this.props;
onSubmit && onSubmit({ submitted: true });
onClose && onClose({ submitted: true });
```

There are only so many ways of shortening code though, sometimes a thorough check can be a necessity. Don't try and prune too much.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use **defaultProps** to provide reasonable defaults, So you don't have to worry about if it's in props or not, you can do this

```
ComponentName.defaultProps = {
  onSubmit: () => {},
  onClose: () => {} // default function
}
```

So you can call your props functions if they are not provided in props these empty functions would be used

Hope it helps